# How to use javascript to display an alert box with the value of a html element in Django Templates?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have an updateview with modelformsets that is rendered in a Django template: 
[image: Modelformset_factory render in django template]

The template renders 3 modelformsets.

I want when a user clicks the div with the `class = "panel-footer"`, see template snippet, the value of `{{ forma.instance.suggestReason }}` is displayed in an alert box. Since the template will render 3 different modelformsets in three different panels with footer, I want the associated `{{ forma.instance.suggestReason }}` for a panel-footer to be displayed in an alert box when each of the divs with the `class = "panel-footer"` is clicked.

Snippet of template:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px">
{% csrf_token %}            
{{ formset.management_form }}
{{ formset.non_form_errors }}           
{% for forma in formset.forms %}
    <div class = "panel panel-primary">
        <div class = "panel-heading">
            <h3 class = "panel-title">{{forma.instance.attackPattern.APid}} : {{forma.instance.attackPattern.name}}</h3>
        </div>   
        <div class = "panel-body">
            {{ forma}}

        </div>
        <div class = "panel-footer">
        {{ forma.instance.suggestReason }}

            </div>
            <a href="#{#% url 'RecSys:apid' forma.instance.attackPattern.APid %#}"></a>
    </div>  
{% endfor %}            
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Update" />
```